# How to Debug Android Wear Application in Eclipse?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I am trying to develop android wear application with handled app.
My Android wear device (Samsung Gear Live) was not detected by ADB.
So , I am signing the wear app and adding it to handled app and signing handled app separately.
Now How to get crash logs from the wear app?

Any body can help on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable developer options and adb debugging on you Wear device to be able to use adb.

1. Open the Settings app and scroll to the bottom.
2. If it doesn't have a Developer Options setting, tap About Phone (or About Tablet), scroll to the bottom, and tap the build number 7 times.
3. Go back and tap Developer Options.
4. Enable USB debugging.

When that is done you can either connect your watch with a usb cable, just like you connect your phone or enable bluetooth debugging like described here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html